# How can I get the sum of gradients immediately after loss.backward()?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient, backpropagation, autograd

I am new to Pytorch, and I am trying to do some importance sampling experiments:
During an evaluation epoch, I calculate the loss for each training sample, and obtain the sum of gradients for this training sample. Finally, I will sort the training samples based on gradients they introduced. For example, if sample A shows a very high gradient sum, it must be an important sample to training. Otherwise, it is not a very important sample.

Note that, the gradients calculated here will not be used to update parameters. In other words, they are only used for selecting importance samples.

I know gradients will be ready somewhere after loss.backward(). But what is the easiest way to grab the summed gradients over the entire model? In my current implementation, I am only allowed to modify one small module with only loss availble, so I don’t have “inputs” or “model”. Is it possible to get the gradients from only “loss”?

Comment: Gradients after backward are stored as the `grad` attribute of tensors that require grad. You can find all tensors involved and sum up their `grad`s. A cleaner way might be to write a backward hook to accumulate gradients to some global variable while backpropagating

Comment: @ihdv  Thanks for your feedback. Could you point me some examplary code to achieve that?

Comment: I put the code example into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradients after backward are stored as the `grad` attribute of tensors that require grad. You can find all tensors involved and sum up their `grad`s. A cleaner way might be to write a backward hook to accumulate gradients to some global variable while backpropagating.

An example is

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

model = nn.Linear(5, 3)
print(model.weight.grad)  # None, since the grads have not been computed yet
print(model.bias.grad)

x = torch.randn(5, 5)
y = model(x)
loss = y.sum()
loss.backward()

print(model.weight.grad)
print(model.bias.grad)
```

output:

```
None
None
tensor([[-0.6164,  1.1585, -3.4117, -4.3192, -3.7273],
        [-0.6164,  1.1585, -3.4117, -4.3192, -3.7273],
        [-0.6164,  1.1585, -3.4117, -4.3192, -3.7273]])
tensor([5., 5., 5.])
```

As you see, you can access the gradients as `param.grad`. If `model` is an `torch.nn.Module` object, you can iterate over its parameters with `for param in model.parameters()`.

Maybe you can also work with backward hooks but I am not that familiar with them to give a code example.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can add model as a new argument to this module to allow "model.parameters".  Currently, a complete loss.backward() is too expensive for each sample, and I actually don't need to update any parameters (all I need is some gradients before they are added to any weights).  Is it possible to make loss.backward() only calculate the gradients for the last 2~3 layers?

Comment: You can probably use `with torch.no_grad()` for the model except for the last 2~3 layers. But I haven't tried this myself before to say for sure